# How to capture a variable in expect script

Tags: linux, expect

I am trying to capture IP of the host on remote serial connection, so that i can ssh into the host later on. But i dont really understand how expect work, and this what i came up with so far.

I tried with the posted code, but seems i cannot get the var to be the value i need, either it is empty or it is the command itself.

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn serialconn
expect -re "#"
send "ip addr list eth0 |grep -m1 inet |cut -d' ' -f6|cut -d/ -f1\r"
set ip {} 
expect {
    -regexp {..#} {
        append ip "${ip}$expect_out(0,string)" 
        exp_continue
    }
}
puts $ip
spawn serialconn finished
expect -re "%"
spawn sudo ssh $ip
```

The question i want to ask is what is -regexp {..#} in my code (i found the code and re-modified it a bit). If someone could explain the whole process it would be great. Thanks

I want the IP to be saved into the variable so that i can sudo ssh into the host.

Answer (score 0):

I copied an example which used 1 not 0:

`$expect_out(1,string)`

Just tried 0 and got the prompt instead of the input. TBH I'm not sure why, or how the matching works, and the manual pages wasn't very helpful on the matter, but you could try different numbers and see if that makes a difference.

Or your regex might be wrong. I've seen the format you've used in above examples, but I just used (.*) in place of the expected data I wanted to capture.